# ARM Assembly: Loop will only iterate once, then inferior error

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

I'm doing a blackjack game for my final project for an assembly course. I have an array of words that represents 52 cards in a deck. My game wont be exactly like blackjack, but I need to demonstrate the basic concept of the game.

I'm trying to loop my deal function twice, but no matter what value I put into r4 (the loop counter) it only prints the output of the deal function once. I've looked at this in GDB and after the first iteration of deal I get an error:

[Inferior 1 (process 1585) exited with code 04]

```
mov r4, #0
cmp r4, #4
beq display_2
add r4, r4, #1
bal deal
```

Whole source code:

```
.equ INPUT, 0
.equ OUTPUT, 1
.equ LOW, 0
.equ HIGH, 1

.equ PIN0, 0    // wipi pin 0 - bcm 17
.equ PIN1, 1    // wipi pin 1 - bcm 18
.equ PIN2, 2    // wipi pin 2 - bcm 27
.equ PIN3, 3    // wipi pin 3 - bcm 22
.equ PIN4, 4    // wipi pin 4 - bcm 23
.equ PIN5, 5    // wipi pin 5 - bcm 24
.equ PIN6, 6    // wipi pin 6 - bcm 25
.equ PIN7, 7    // wipi pin 7 - bcm 4

.global main
.data
format: .asciz "r1=%d\n"
.balign 4
// Create a deck of 52 cards
deck:
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10

.text
// ripped from C++ compiler's assembly output
.align 2
.L3: .word 1321528399

main:
push {lr}
bl wiringPiSetup

mov r0, #PIN0
mov r1, #OUTPUT
bl pinMode

mov r0, #PIN1
mov r1, #OUTPUT
bl pinMode

mov r0, #PIN2
mov r1, #OUTPUT
bl pinMode

mov r0, #PIN3
mov r1, #OUTPUT
bl pinMode

mov r0, #PIN4
mov r1, #OUTPUT
bl pinMode

deal:
// the following code was disassembled from the C++ compiler's
// rand function
mov     r0, #0
bl      time
mov     r3, r0
mov     r0, r3
bl      srand
bl      rand

mov     r2, r0
ldr     r3, .L3
smull   r1, r3, r3, r2
mov     r1, r3, asr #4
mov     r3, r2, asr #31
rsb     r3, r3, r1
mov     r1, #52
mul     r3, r1, r3
rsb     r3, r3, r2
// end of C++ compiler's code
ldr r0, =format
// mov the random number generated (r3) into r1 for printing
mov r1, r3
// take the same value and store it also into r7 to preserve it
mov r7, r1
bl printf
ldr r0, =format
ldr r1, =deck
// setup r9 as the increment value leading to the next index
// of the array
mov r9, #4
// multiply into r8 the random number times the increment value
// of the array (4 bytes)
mul r8, r7, r9
// r8 now holds the randomized card just dealt to the player
// add this to the players score and get the actual value
// at from the address
add r1, r1, r8
ldr r1, [r1]
// mov into r7 the players score to preserve it
mov r7, r1
bl printf

display_2:
mov r4, #0
l:
cmp r4, #2
bne deal
add r4, r4, #1

bal l
// write the players score to the led display
mov r0, r7
bl digitalWriteByte
```

Sample output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./6leds.out 
r1=50 // the random index chosen
r1=10 // the value stored at that array index
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./6leds.out 
r1=6
r1=7
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./6leds.out 
r1=6
r1=7
```

^ I would like it to do this twice instead of once

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: Well I used the C++ rand function (disassembled) lol. I'm just hoping someone with a background in C/C++ and assembly will be able to see what's going on with this.

Comment: I do not see any loop in the code you've posted. A loop would require testing the counter and branching back to an instruction above where it is incremented. This is not a minimal complete example and thus it is very hard to tell you what is wrong. A specific question to ask yourself is "Which branch and which label form the 'loop' I am asking about?"

Comment: Edit: nevermind, what Zalman said makes perfect since. I was thinking about it the wrong way. Making some changes atm...

Comment: Sounded like you wanted to run the code on the other side of the "bal deal" twice, but the "bal deal" does not close the loop. Unless the code you've mentioned is immediately after the end of that block, which is impossible to tell from what you have posted, there is no branch to form the loop. Does execution ever get back to the cmp instruction after the first "bal deal" is executed?

Comment: When you single-step your code in GDB, where are you expecting a conditional branch (like `beq`) to be taken, but instead if falls through?  Use `layout reg` to watch register values change, too.  If you can't debug this yourself, then update to show all of what's supposed to be a loop, so this is a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the OP with the whole source code. My issue is still fundamentally the same. I'm not sure how to write the conditional logic in assembly to get it looping twice. Thanks for telling me about layout reg Peter.

Comment: Also it the program is crashing, you want to identify the instruction that is faulting. Running it under the debugger and requedt a backtrace is a way to do this. It is not clear from the question how the code is exiting. (Correct ways are to return from `main` or to call `exit`.)

Comment: If you want to something as "deal" happen exactly twice, you can avoid loop completely by putting "deal" functionality into subroutine (i.e. make it follow some calling convention, or design your custom one, how it should be called, and add return at end), then you can call it twice like: `bl deal` `bl deal`  -> done.

Comment: ^ Hey that worked! All I changed in the deal function is I added push {lr} to the start of the function, and pop {pc} at the end of it. Is that what you mean by 'add return at end'? Or did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

A loop might be structured like so:

```
    // Initialize loop counter. Note this is outside the loop body.
    mov #r4, 0
loop_entry:
    // Test if the loop is done. This is a "while (...) { }" or for style loop
    cmp #r4, <loop_limt>
    bge loop_exit
    // code that you want to execute multiple times.
    // In the above this would be everything between deal: and display_2:
    <...>
    add r4, r4, #1
    bal loop_entry

loop_exit:
    // Do stuff after the loop.
```

In the code you posted, the initialization to zero effectively happens inside of the loop. I would expect this to produce an infinite loop, not one which terminates after one execution. (E.g. I don't see how the `bal l` ever gets executed. You can verify this by stepping through in the debugger.)

The only simple thing I can think of that you might be getting hung up on is the difference between labels and functions. In the code you posted, the only label that identifies a function is `main:`. Elsewhere, the code just keeps executing past a label in a straight line. (There is of course nothing special about the `main:` label either, it is how it is used.) So after the second `printf` following `deal:`, the `move r4, #0` under `display_2:` gets executed.